# Zoom com dedos em app

Tags: android

Estive a ver que existe o zoombutton e o zoomcontrols no Android Studio mas pelo que analisei nenhum faz zoom com os dedos.

Como posso fazer zoom com os dedos em uma aplicação Android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isso seria detectar o movimento e depois executar o código que transforma a *View* onde foi feito o movimento.

Para detectar o movimento usamos a classe [ScaleGestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html) passando a ela um [SimpleOnScaleGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener.html):

```
//Classe que herda de SimpleOnScaleGestureListener a
//ser passada ao ScaleGestureDetector
private class ScaleListener extends SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        //Factor de zoom correspondente ao movimento feito
        float scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();

        //Executa o zoom
        performZoom(scaleFactor);
        return true;
    }
}

//Criar o ScaleGestureDetector
scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this,new ScaleListener());
```

O *ScaleGestureDetector* é usado da seguinte forma:

```
//Associa um OnTouchListener à nossa view
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        v.performClick();
        //Chamar o onTouchEvent do nosso ScaleGestureDetector
        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Até aqui tudo fácil, a dificuldade poderá ser escrever o método `performZoom`.

Se for uma *ImageView* poderá ser qualquer coisa do tipo:

```
private ImageView imageView;
private float scale = 1f;

private void performZoom(float scaleFactor) {
    scale *= scaleFactor;
    scale = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scale, 5.0f));
    imageView.setScaleX(scale);
    imageView.setScaleY(scale);
}
```

Comment: tenho que criar uma classe com o código que está ai cima ou pode ser na  MainActivity principal.

Comment: @Rodolfo Pode ser tudo na Activity.

Comment: +1 Achei bem bacana desta forma.