# Como deslocar uma imagem aumentada com dedo na ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview

Com base [nessa resposta da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74540/zoom-com-dedos-em-app/74580#74580)  quando estiver com zoom bem ampliado como movimentar a imagem com dedo para ver as outra parte da imagem.

Answer (score 1):

Podes tentar usar a CropView da biblioteca scissors da Lyft.

```
<com.lyft.android.scissors.CropView
    android:id="@+id/crop_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cropviewViewportHeightRatio="1"
    />
```

https://github.com/lyft/scissors

Toda a informação de como usar está no link em cima. Só não precisas de usar a função crop.

Para adicionala ao teu projeto basta escrever no teu gradle o seguinte:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.lyft:scissors:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: valeu, seria uma biblioteca de terceiros mas eu queria uma solução para aquele problema.